# FileHistory no usable drives found

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I am trying to use the FileHistory feature of Windows 10 to automatically backup documents to another partition. As admin I was able to do this without problems. However, when logged in as a regular user, I get the message "No usable drives found" and am unable to select the other partition. (The dialog does not list any drive or partition at all.) How can I get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Some suggest if the drive or partition has been made part of a Windows library, then it will not show up. Have you tried restarting your PC?

Comment: The entire drive or just a folder on the drive?

Comment: I want to use the same drive/partition for both users.

Comment: Rebooting did not help.